# Refactor a SQL query

Tags: sql

I have two sql queries which outputs same and right result. I need help to understand why one query takes more time than other.

1. Sql query is nested query

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name
FROM people p INNER JOIN stars s 
            ON p.id = s.person_id 
            AND movie_id IN ( SELECT movie_id
                FROM stars ss
                WHERE ss.person_id = ( SELECT id
                      FROM people pp
                      WHERE pp.name = 'Kevin Bacon' AND pp.birth = 1958 ) 
            )
            AND NOT (p.name = 'Kevin Bacon' AND p.birth = 1958)
ORDER BY name ASC
```

This Query takes about 4 seconds to fetch results from 150K rows

2. Query Uses Joins

```
SELECT DISTINCT pp.name
FROM
        people p JOIN stars s ON p.id = s.person_id JOIN
        stars ss ON s.movie_id = ss.movie_id JOIN
        people pp ON pp.id = ss.person_id
WHERE p.name = 'Kevin Bacon' AND p.birth = 1958 AND p.id IS NOT pp.id

ORDER BY pp.name ASC
```

This query takes about 40 seconds to fetch records. I want to use this query but It is quite slow, Is there any way to optimize this query.

## Structure of DB

[image]

[image: Query1 Output]

[image: Query2 Output]

Comment: Both the queries don't look same. Are both the queries returning the exact same results? The first query has an 'NOT condition as well, which is missing in the second query

Comment: I think DBMS's optimizer was smart enough to reduce size of `people` just to the row with `p.name = 'Kevin Bacon' AND p.birth = 1958`, and so these joins take no time. You can check optimizer plans yourself

Comment: Could you add a tag that specifies which DB engine you are running on?

Comment: According to the first query you would get p.names of people other than Kevin Bacon whose birthdate is 1958. The second query specifically looks for Kevin Bacon with brithday of 1958. Are you sure you are getting identical results

Comment: The first query doesn't look quite right to me. The second query doesn't do whatever the first query does. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry, Sorry I put the wrong query earlier, Please check again.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph this query is fetching "the list of names of all people who starred in a movie in which Kevin Bacon(birth 1958) also starred."

Comment: @BlackSwan I have corrected the second query. It was actually wrong. Now it working same as the first query. Please check the screenshots in my question

Comment: I can only refer you again to the accepted answer at the link above

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

try to add a primary keys on your tables (or index)

```
ALTER TABLE people
ADD CONSTRAINT people_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE stars
ADD CONSTRAINT stars_pk PRIMARY KEY (person_id , movie_id);
```

you can view the explain plain for watch how to optimize your queries, in the explain plain you can see the query behavior and send to us for more help.

Comment: Yes, we can use indexes on fields to make it fast, but see first query gets results in 4 seconds without indexing any column Second query is taking too long. So I am skeptical about the second query. Is it using wrong or extra JOIN, It is fetching right data set though